# How to assign multiple variables to a dictionary

Tags: python

Part of the goal of my program is to show all the books in the dictionary and for the user to have the ability to search for a title of a book.

I created a function called retrieve_books where I declared a list called list_of_books. Then I opened the file called "books.csv" to read form the list_of_books. Then I appended the list_of_books with the title, author and year in the dictionary and then returned the list_of_books but I keep getting a "ValueError: Too many values to unpack".

I have tried looking through StackOverflow and have found similar ways to solve the problem but presently, none of them correct the issue. I have tried creating a conditional statement to resolve the issue. I have also tried unpacking one variable at a time. I tried using the keyword Values or Items. If I modify anything different in the in the code it gives me indentation errors.

```
 def retrieve_books():
    list_of_books = {}

    with open("books.csv", "r") as list_of_books:
        for books in list_of_books:
            # Extracts the values from the CSV data
            title, author, year = list_of_books

            # Creates a dictionary from the csv data and adds it to the books list
            list_of_books.append({
                "title": title,
                "author": author,
                "year": year
            })

    return list_of_books
```

Comment: *where I declared a list called list_of_books* -- `list_of_books = {}` is the declaration of a dict, not a list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not actually parsing the csv line here. You need to use the csv module to properly parse a csv file.

```
import csv

def retrieve_books():
    list_of_books = []
    with open('books.csv', 'r') as csvfile:
        csvreader = csv.reader(csvfile)
        for row in csvreader:
            list_of_books.append({
                'title': row[0] if 0<len(row) else None,
                'author': row[1] if 1<len(row) else None,
                'year': row[2] if 2<len(row) else None
             })
    return list_of_books
```

Comment: Thank you so much, that fixed the problem. I didn't know that it should be read by csv.reader although the 'r' should have been a clue...

Answer (score 0):

You have quite a lot of namespace collisions:

```py
def retrieve_books():
    list_of_books = {}
```

At this point `list_of_books` is an empty dictionary.

```
with open("books.csv", "r") as list_of_books:
    for books in list_of_books:
        # Extracts the values from the CSV data
```

At this point list_of_books is a `file` object, which you iterate linewise.

```
title, author, year = list_of_books
```

This unpacks *the whole file* into three variables.  Unless you have three lines it will fail, but in any case what you want is:

```
title, author, year = books
```

Note this will still fail if there are more than 3 entries in books.  Presumably you do something to books first (like splitting it by `","`, as in the code presented it's just a string, so this will fail (it will try to unpack the string by character, so if it more than 3 chars long it will bail).

```
list_of_books.append({
                      "title": title,
                       "author": author,
                       "year": year})
```

Now we're appending to the *file object*.  If your code got this far it would fail with `AttributeError`.  You need to call your `list_of_books` something different.  But you also want it to be a list:

```
results = []
results.append(...)
```

The same goes for the end, where you return `list_of_books`, which is still a file object.

The moral is: name your `list_of_books` something else, or name your file object (`as ...`) something else, and declare your list as a list.

Answer (score 0):

Given that you wanted a list consisting of each book detail in the form of a dictionary, you could get every value inside the record using `books.split(",")`. Your code defined `list_of_books` as a list and then proceeded to use it as a file object which raised an `Attribute Error` which is why the dictionary could not be appended.
This code uses a separate variable `bookList` to append each record from the csv file and return the final output.

```
def retrieve_books():
    bookList = []
    with open("books.csv", "r") as list_of_books:
        for books in list_of_books:
            # Extracts the values from the CSV data
            title, author, year = books.split(",")
            # Creates a dictionary from the csv data and adds it to the books list
            book = {
                "title": title,
                "author": author,
                "year": year
            }
            
            bookList.append(book)

    return bookList
```

Comment: It's preferable to use the csv module to read csv files. Splitting on comma won't always work, and neither will reading line by line. CSV files, particularly those you're importing from something like Excel, can contain quoted strings, and those can contain both commas and line breaks, so those need to be taken into account.

Comment: That's a great point. I just used this to remain consistent with the OP's question. I'll include the alt answer with the csv module in an edit.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, when you said "I declared a list called list_of_books" you actually declared a dictionary.

Secondly, you had reassigned a file object to the namespace list_of_books and which should have given you an error when you tried to 'append' the dictionary object, but your code didn't even reach there, because instead of unpacking the element for that particular iteration you were trying to unpack the entire list_of_books object which gave you the "ValueError: Too many values to unpack".

Without changing any of your logic, to make this working the code should look like this:

```
 def retrieve_books():
    list_of_books = []

    with open("books.csv", "r") as books:
        for book in books:
            # Extracts the values from the CSV data
            title, author, year = book.split(",")

            # Creates a dictionary from the csv data and adds it to the books list
            list_of_books.append({
                "title": title,
                "author": author,
                "year": year
            })

    return list_of_books
```